BullMQ NestJS external process configuration
I'm trying to configure an external process because my jobs were stalling:
    BullModule.registerQueue({
      name: 'compute',
      processors: [
        {
          callback: compute,
          concurrency: 2,
        },
      ],
    }),

I've tried to set up concurrency as shown here, but it's not working. Since it's an external process, I can't use the @Processor decorator.
My jobs are reported as fails (even if they successfully end) because I've got this error:

Error: Missing lock for job 84 failed

After reading online, it appears that I can maybe increase the lockDuration parameter to avoid that, but same, I don't know where to setup that.
Can you help? Thanks!!

if you want to set the lockDuration, set it when you create a new queue
this is the code to set below:
export const bulkDiscountQueue = new Queue('bulk-discount-queue', {
  redis,
  settings: { lockDuration: 5 * 60 * 1000 }, //5 mins
});

also try to set maxStalledCount to 0, due to specific implementation Bull can overwrite real error with a useless Missing lock for job, and I hope this can help.
ref
and your case register new queue by a module, do this:
BullModule.registerQueue({
  name: 'compute',
  processors: [
    {
      callback: compute,
      concurrency: 2,
    },
  ],
  settings: { lockDuration: 5 * 60 * 1000 },
});


Hello, thanks for your answer! I would like to do it with NestJS BullMQ (cf my code sample), I don't create any queue with new Queue with this package

so yeah, registerQueue have the option settings inside, check it out

Unfortunately, no, settings doesn't have a lockDuration option

can you provide your BullModule import?

Sure, here you go:
import { BullModule } from '@nestjs/bullmq'
settings is of type AdvancedRepeatOptions
cf
https://github.com/taskforcesh/bullmq/blob/master/src/interfaces/queue-options.ts
and https://github.com/taskforcesh/bullmq/blob/master/src/interfaces/advanced-options.ts#L3

ah, my code uses @nestjs/bull only, i look around and see the lockDuration in the WorkerOptions, did you use new Worker?

Nope, with @nestjs/bullmq I don't really instantiate a new Worker
